# Embed IPython in PyCharm

Tags: python, ipython, pycharm

I built a program thats ends up with 'IPython.embed()' line for interactive user interface.

When I run it in a regural python/cmd shell it works just fine, but when I tried to run my program in the PyCharm IDE it didn't work right.
My bottom purpose is to be able to use the PyCharm debugger on my code and be able to put breakpoints.

Why doesn't my code works the same on the PyCharm console and how can I fix it?

p.s. I tried it with Eclipse and it did a similiar problem.

Edit: I use python 2.7, IPython 3 and PyCharm 2.7.3 on Windows 7

Comment: You've left is in the dark. What version of PyCharm, what version of IPython? What OS? All these things are relevant.

Comment: What your project interpreter (python version) in your pycharm project ? (Run/Debug Configurations => Python interpreter)

Comment: Note: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/ipython.html

Comment: I use intrepreter Python 2.7.10, with IPython installed